# Invalid value for transfer while using ipcRenderer.postMessage of electron

Tags: electron, postmessage

Invalid value for transfer while using ipcRenderer.postMessage of electron?I don't know what's wrong with it

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  const { port1 } = new MessageChannel();
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  ipcRenderer.postMessage('port', { message: 'hello' }, [port1]);
```

[image]

[image]

I wonder if something wrong in my preload.js?
[image]

I upload all my code to github
https://github.com/codeh2o/electronVuePreloadIssue

Comment: Your code snippet is (nearly) exactly what is written in the documentation, so either you don't use a valid electron version, or there is something else at the 23rd line. Can you check that the included code is indeed the 23rd line and maybe try checking the value of `port1` ?

Comment: thanks for view , the 23rd is quite simple. I upload all my code into github . I wonder if I do something wrong in my preload.js because I pass ipcRenderer to in the file.

Comment: i also pass `ipcRenderer` there, so that shouldn't be the problem. But i never used the third input argument :(